# Function parameter is not being passed. How to correctly pass parameter into function of another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to to call a function `file2Function(getValue)` of a file `(page2.js)` from another JavaScript File `(page1.js)` to open new page in browser and display some data on it using parameter passed via`myFunction1(e) into file2Function as file2Function(itemFromItems)`. So `file2Function(getValue)`should take value of `var itemFromItems` and should display on `page2.html`. But it is displaying "undefined" for `getValue`. Kindly help me finding out where I am doing Mistake. Thank You.

[image: outPut in page1.html]

[image: output after page load page2.html]

```js
// page1.js

function file1Function()
{
  var secPage1 = document.getElementById("page1Section");
  var heading = document.createElement("h4");
  var anchor= document.createElement('a');

  anchor.setAttribute('href',"#");
  anchor.innerText = "Click Me";
  anchor.addEventListener("click", myFunction1);
  heading.appendChild(anchor);
  secPage1.appendChild(heading);
  anchor.id=1;

  function myFunction1(e) {
   var itemFromItems = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id");
   console.log("item",itemFromItems);
   file2Function(itemFromItems);
   
  }
}


// page2.js
var globalVar;
function file2Function(getValue)
{
 console.log("getValue",getValue);

 window.open("page2.html");
    // window.open("https://www.google.com/");
    
    globalVar=getValue;
 console.log("globalVarNow",globalVar);
}

function loadDynamicData()
{

    var para=document.getElementById("paraId");
    console.log(para);
    para.innerText=globalVar+" : value from myFunction1 (Click Event)";


    var secPage2 = document.getElementById("page2Section");
  var headingJS2 = document.createElement("h4");
  headingJS2.innerText=" This is dynamic heading";
  secPage2.appendChild(headingJS2);
    console.log(para);
}
```

```html
<!-- page1.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="js/page1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/page2.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="file1Function()">
 <h3>This is page1</h3>

<section id="page1Section">
 
</section>


<script>
</script>

</body>
</html>


<!-- page2.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body onload="loadDynamicData()">

<h3>This is page2</h3>

<section id="page2Section">
 
</section>
<p id="paraId"></p>

<script src="js/page2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are these pages local or in the same domain?

Comment: no. these are local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `globalVar` is a global variable, but the value you are assigning to it in `file2Function()` is accessable only within its scope, that is why you are getting `undefined`, because `loadDynamicData()` has no access to the new value of `globalVar`.

You could call `loadDynamicData()` from `file2Function()` and pass `getValue` as an argument, but since you need to open `page2` before executing `loadDynamicData()` it won't work.

What I suggest is you pass `getValue` along with your `URL` as a query parameter and get it from inside `loadDynamicData()`, it'll work fine.

`SOLUTION:`

```
function file2Function(getValue)
{
    window.open("page2.html?value="+getValue);
  // window.open("https://www.google.com/");
}

function loadDynamicData()
{
    var url_string = window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var globalVar = url.searchParams.get("value");


    var para=document.getElementById("paraId");
    console.log(para);
    para.innerText=globalVar+" : value from myFunction1 (Click Event)";


    var secPage2 = document.getElementById("page2Section");
        var headingJS2 = document.createElement("h4");
        headingJS2.innerText=" This is dynamic heading";
        secPage2.appendChild(headingJS2);
    console.log(para);

}
```

If you want to hide the values you can use `sessionStorage` instead of query parameters:

```
function file2Function(getValue)
{
  sessionStorage.setItem('value', getValue)
  window.open("page2.html");
  // window.open("https://www.google.com/");
}

function loadDynamicData()
{
    var globalVar = sessionStorage.getItem('value')

    var para=document.getElementById("paraId");
    console.log(para);
    para.innerText=globalVar+" : value from myFunction1 (Click Event)";


    var secPage2 = document.getElementById("page2Section");
        var headingJS2 = document.createElement("h4");
        headingJS2.innerText=" This is dynamic heading";
        secPage2.appendChild(headingJS2);
    console.log(para);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting your efforts in replying to my query. Should I place file2Function() inside page1.js after file1function()?

Comment: is it possible to hide the value the from URL or replace it with any dummy text without affecting its (value) usage in function?

Comment: I found many urls like [this](https://www.daraz.pk/products/infinix-note-7-4gb-ram-128gb-rom-695-display-white-i144028188-s1305302880.html?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.list.4.43b16f9a4ofWak&search=1)  `containing=1` in the end of every single product page (dynamic page). Can you briefly explain this too or suggest any related article? I know its not relevant to the original query but it will help me gaining better understanding of  URL related concepts as well.

Comment: `Should I place file1Function() inside page1.js after file1function()`. No, you shouldn't, it was a typo, I meant `file2Function()`. I already edited it.

Comment: `is it possible to hide the value the from URL...?` The best way I see to do that is using `sessionStorage`, I added it on the answer

Comment: `I found many urls like this containing=1 in the end of every single product page `: I am not sure about your specific case, but the queries are parameters you pass through URL and it can be accessible from other pages. It is more common to be used in PHP through the methods `POST` and `GET`. Probably `containing` is a variable and `1` is its value, it may be the amount of products that is in your cart or that is being purchased.